# Please tell me why use "sleep()" in pthreads of PHP

Tags: php, pthreads

[image]

Please tell me why use "sleep()" in pthreads of PHP

Comment: Many uses. For example, making curl requests you might want a delay between sending multiple requests. Or a delay between sending mails. I have no idea why it's been used in your example

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php maybe when you understand what does this function do (if you don't know), you find out why it's used in your code? I have no idea..

Comment: Thanks,i have limited knowledge with pthreads. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sleep is used to Delays the program execution for the given number of seconds. in phthreads.

Answer (score 0):

The sleep() function delays execution of the current script for a specified number of seconds.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo date('h:i:s') . "<br>";

//sleep for 10 seconds
sleep(10);

//start again
echo date('h:i:s');
?>

</body>
</html>
```